# How to find the index of the furthest item in a list from a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Leetcode has a question to calculate the max distance between taken and empty seats in a list. I'm having trouble trying to get the index of the seat that is furthest away from a seat taken. The current code calculates the max distance, just not the index of the seat that is furthest away.
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1] would be an example list. 1 is a seat taken and 0 is empty. I want to find the index of the 0 that is furthest away from 1.

```
person_idx = None
last_idx = len(seats) - 1
dist = 0

# scan for each seats
for cur_idx, seat in enumerate(seats):
    # this seat is taken by someone
    if seat == 1:
        if person_idx is None:
            # No person on the left, Alex seat on left hand side
            dist = max(dist, cur_idx)
        else:
            # Surrounded by two person, Alex seat on the middle
            dist = max(dist, (cur_idx - person_idx) // 2)
        person_idx = cur_idx
        print(person_idx)

    # No person on the right, Alex seat on the right hand side
dist = max(dist, last_idx - person_idx)

print(dist)
```

Comment: Are you referring to this problem - `Maximum Distance to closest Person`  https://leetcode.com/problems/maximize-distance-to-closest-person/

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I have the answer but I wanted to know how you would get the index of the seat that is furthest away from someone else.

Comment: The code above answers the questions on leetcode. But I just wanted to know if it's possible to get the index of the empty seat that was furthest away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get the next index of 1 from the given seat index:

```
def GetNextIndex(seats, current):
    return [seats[current+1:]].index(1) + current + 1 # Returns index of next full seat

seat = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
GetNextIndex(seats, 0)
```

You can use this for all the ones that you find (index - current = distance) and compare the max distance, or you can modify the function to return the distance itself

- Note that you need to halve the distances in this problem, because you are finding the middle

Comment: Don't believe this is what OP asked for.